# JSF custom component with @FacesComponent is not found in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsf, custom-component

I want to create a custom JSF 2.0 component but can't get it to work.
My component is defined like this:

```
 @FacesComponent(value = "myCustomComponent")
 public class CommaSeperatedOutput extends UIComponentBase { ... }
```

The taglib looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd" version="2.0"> 
<namespace>http://www.company.com/tags</namespace>
<tag>
    <tag-name>custom</tag-name>
      <component>
        <component-type>myCustomComponent</component-type>
      </component>
</tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

My faces-config looks like this:

```
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: JSF1068: Component with componenttype myCustomComponent could not be instantiated.
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: myCustomComponent not found.
```

Not sure if it is important, but I'm using Spring 3.1 together with JSF 2.1 here. So dependencies are managed by Spring.

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: This is definitely a Spring problem. The JSF part looks fine. So I added the `[spring]` tag so that you also get attention from the Spring guys.

Comment: instead of Custom Component you can also give Composite Component a try.

Comment: This works a treat mate.

Answer (score 4):

*[moving author's solution here]*

Seems like Spring is the bad guy here.
I've removed the annotation `@FacesComponent(value = "myCustomComponent")` from the component and defined it instead in my faces-config like this:

```
<component>
    <component-type>myCustomComponent</component-type>
    <component-class>com.company.jsf.component.CommaSeperatedOutput</component-class>
</component>
```

Now it works.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively, and since you've configured your faces-config.xml file to use the Spring Container, you could use the Spring annotation `@Component("myCustomComponent")`

Comment: Nope, that means that the custom component would become a singleton. That is not what I wanted here.

Comment: Follow it up with a second annotation to manipulate the scope: @Scope("request") or @Scope("prototype") for example. Try this cheat sheet for annotations: http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/spring-annotations